# Annotation Related to union-subclass

Tags: hibernate

I'm newbie to Hibernate Annoation.Kindly help me for the below scenerio.

//xml File

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <union-subclass name="com.SubFilePO" table="JAV_SubFile" extends="com.subFile.CoreSubFilePO" >
        <property name="NAME" type="string"/>
        <property name="AGE" type="string"/>
        <property name="GROUP" type="string"/>
    </union-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

/Following code Which I done Annotation

//SubFilePo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JAV_SubFile")
public class SubFilePo extends com.subFile.CoreSubFilePO implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String NAME;
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private String AGE;
    @Column(name = "GROUP")
    private String GROUP;

    //some code
 }
```

My Question is like whether I need to specify the annotation related to "union-subclass"?